# By clicking text how to change clicked text to another text in React.js

Tags: reactjs, text

I am new in React.js and could not find any answer to this question.

I have a blog for commentaries, and when I click on the title of a comment, the title should change to another text. How would I do that?

[image: comment and title]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `onClick` function and store your title in a state variable.

Here is an example :

```
class Title extends Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.state() {
         title: "Click here"
      }
   }

   changeTitle = () => {
      this.setState({ title: "New title" });
   };

   render() {
       return <h1 onClick={this.changeTitle}>{this.state.title}</h1>;
   }
}
```

You can find more examples here : [Handling Events - React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)

**Update :** You can now use [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) with React 16.8

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Title = () => {
   const [title, setTitle] = useState("Click here");

   return <h1 onClick={() => setTitle("New title")}>{title}</h1>;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Either you can store the text in `state` variable and `onClick` of text update the `state` value, or maintain a `bool` in `state` whether the text has been clicked or not, if yes then show first text otherwise another one,

Try this by storing the text in `state`:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
     super();
     this.state= {title: 'Click text'}
  }
  
  render(){
     return <div onClick= {() => this.setState({title:'New text'})}>{this.state.title}</div>
  } 
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Try this by using a `bool` in `state` variable:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
      constructor(){
         super();
         this.state= {clicked: true}
      }
      
      render(){
         return <div onClick= {() => this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})}>
         {
            this.state.clicked? 'First Text' : 'Second Text'
         }
         <br/>
         * click on text to toggle
         </div>
      } 
    }

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please feel free to copy the whole thing of mine below, which is a completely tested source (which has everything, e.g. the *defaultProps*):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class InterchangeableText extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         title: this.props.defaultText
      }
      this.changeTitle = this.changeTitle.bind(this);
   }

   changeTitle() {
      this.setState({ 
          title: this.props.changedText
      });
   }

   render() {
       return <div onClick={this.changeTitle}>{this.state.title}</div>;
   }

}

InterchangeableText.defaultProps = {
    defaultText: 'defaultText',
    changedText: 'changedText'
}
```

Next, in another component where you render the above component, please add:

```
// ...
render() {
    return <InterchangeableText defaultText="some default text" changedText="text changed!"/>
}
```